# Normalizing a table by rank

Tags: sql-server

I have a Table which looks like this:

### Rank      Account

### | 1 |      | A1 |

### | 2 |      | A2 |

### | 3 |      | A3 |

### | 1 |      | A4 |

### | 2 |      | A5 |

### | 1 |      | A6 |

In it all the Accounts which are linked together are ranked, done in a previous stored procedure. I want to now break down this table so that whenever a rank goes back down to 1 it takes the previous rows and writes it into a new table. for example Accounts A1,A2,A3 are all written into a separate table as are Accounts A4,A5 and Account A6. How would I do this.

The eventual goal being too right each table into a CSV file. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do this, you will need to add a third column to your table.  This column would need to either be:

- A grouping column that shows which Accounts are linked together, so that it will have the same value for A1, A2, A3.   And another common value for A4 & A5, and another value for A6.  Or
- An ordinal column, such as an IDENTITY column, that you can use to tell in what order the Accounts were inserted, so that you can use that to figure out which items are grouped together.

Without a third column, there is NO WAY to know that A2 goes with A1 and not A4 or A6.

Comment: Could a cursor through each of them till I see rank=1. I am not sure how to do that but its a way I think.

Comment: No, because what would you order the cursor by?   If your table had an ordinal column, then yes, you could do that.   If you're thinking that if you don't use ORDER BY, that the rows will come out in the order they were inserted, I'm afraid that's not the case.

Comment: Hi all, for future people what I did was add a seedable column and a column with a Account ID so A1,A2,A3 is Account ID 1 A4,A5 is Account ID 2, in the temp table then I was able to group it using the method mentioned by tab